# Аэропорты и ЖД на Yandex карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Нужно подсветить на яндекс-карте аэропорты, морские и речные порты, а так-же железные дороги России. Причем отдельно Октябрьскую, Московскую ЖД и т.д. Как это можно сделать с использованием API Yandex карт?

Comment: добавка «или других сервисов» сразу превращает вопрос в кандидат на закрытие по причине множественности заданных вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

Геометрию геообъектов в API Карт вам Яндекс не вернёт. А вот подсветить порты можно поиском "порт" на базе [примера из песочницы](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/search_control_ppo).